# Enable SVG on Apache without .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, svg

I'm using the following code to enable svg's to work on my server. I get tired of doing that though, is there a server setting through apache or php to enable this to always allow svgs?

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to "enable" svg documents?

Comment: You don't need .htaccess but you can add it to your apache config. You should only have to do that once. Not sure why you keep having to do it. @arkascha it's probably not reading the mime type correctly on his server. Usually a msg like this will happen . `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml` and the image will show as broken.

Comment: @PanamaJack I don't know, since the OP did not write what the actual issue is. I never had an issue as you describe on various systems...

Comment: The issue is as @PanamaJack described. I get broken images when I use SVG's. I've had other servers that handled them without having to use the htaccess fix, so I know it's possible. I just wasn't sure where and what to change to make it work.

Comment: @arkascha if you use a hosting company, many of them configure common mime types for you in their image and it's in the apache config already. So it just works. If you get a VPS or Dedicated server `sometimes` it's not done and you have to set the server up the way you want it to work. Depends on the host.

Comment: @paper_robots the only other pace you can use it is the Apache config or vhost file. You have to have access to that on your server. Otherwise it has to go in the .htaccess file that you have access to.